# pymysql failure on cur.execute()

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

I have a MySQL DB with two tables. `Files` keeps a record of CSV files previously parsed - I can successfully read all its rows into a variable

I then wind through the files in a specified folder and perform the following actions:

1. Is the filename format one I'm interested in - e.g. `21-05-14.CSV` and it's not in the list of previously parsed files. If it's been parsed previously or isn't the right type of file, ignore it!
2. Parse files of interest to extract into a variable, `PowerGenList` all the time:power value pairs
3. For each row in `PowerGenList` extract the `timestampval` and the `powerval` and use them to construct SQL to add these values into a MySQL database table, `DTP`

```
Example PowerGenList = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012'], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 14, 10), '0.012']]
```

4. When I run this through VSCode in Debug mode (Python3.6) I print the SQL. `INSERT INTO DTP (DT,PWR) VALUES('2015-12-29 14:10:00','0.012');`, which looks OK to me?
5. When I run `cur.execute(sql)`, I get the following errors and it jumps straight to the `except:` path - **(I am completely in the dark as to how to analyse why it's failed)**

```
Exception has occurred: InterfaceError
(0, '')
  File "/home/greg/currentGenerated/SBEAM/SunnyCSV2DB-v6.py", line 210, in add_days_power_to_DTP_table
    cur.execute(sql)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/greg/currentGenerated/SBEAM/SunnyCSV2DB-v6.py", line 215, in add_days_power_to_DTP_table
    addcon.rollback()
  File "/home/greg/currentGenerated/SBEAM/SunnyCSV2DB-v6.py", line 245, in <module>
    add_days_power_to_DTP_table(con, PowerGenList)
```

The function code is:

```
def add_days_power_to_DTP_table(addcon, PowerGenList):
    PowerGenList.__len__
    print(PowerGenList)
    table_name = 'DTP'
    timestamp_column  = 'DT'
    power_column = 'PWR'
    cur = addcon.cursor()
    try:
        for row in PowerGenList:
            timestampval    = row[0]
            powerval        = row[1]
            sql             = "INSERT INTO %s (%s,%s) VALUES('%s','%s');" % (table_name, timestamp_column, power_column, timestampval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), powerval)
            print('DTP SQL statement = ' + sql)
            cur.execute(sql)
            addcon.commit()
    except:
        #print 'DB append failed!'
        syslog.syslog('SunnyData DB append failed')
        addcon.rollback()
```

In case it's relevant, my tables are meant to be structured like this:

```
def recreateDB():  # NOT USED but useful for reference & debug - keep up to date!
  NewFiles = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'SunnyData2'.'Files' ('idfiles' int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'FN' varchar(15) NOT NULL, 'FD' DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('idfiles'));"
  NewDTP = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'SunnyData2'.'DTP' ('idDTP' int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'DT' DATETIME NOT NULL, 'PWR' varchar(6) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('idDTP'));"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the bug. Look in the code you have used semicolon at the last. I have removed it. Give it a try. I never used a semicolon while execute same.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s,%s) VALUES('%s','%s') ; " % (table_name, timestamp_column, power_column, timestampval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), powerval)
```

Also, do not use above formatting instead use 'f' or 'format' method like mentioned below.

```
sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({timestamp_column},{power_column}) VALUES('{timestampval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}','{powerval}')"
```

Much more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Tushar
On your first point about the trailing semi-colon (;) - I use exactly the same format, with the ; when I add the filename to the `Files` table to record which files I've parsed and that works fine
```
sql2 = "INSERT INTO %s (%s, %s) VALUES ('%s', '%s');" % (table_name,filename,filedate,filenameval,filedateval)
```

On your second point, thanks for showing an alternative way of doing it. It does look cleaner and I'll try it but I don't think it will solve the issue I have. I'll respond again when I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Full working CSV parser for Sunny Boy Solar inverters

Maria DB: SunnyData2, tables:
Files: (keeps a record of previously parsed files)

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FN       | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FD       | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| IDXFiles | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

DTP: (Record of non-zero power readings aggregated for all CSV files)

```
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idxDTP | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| DT     | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PWR    | varchar(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Python prog to parse a folder of SunnyBoy inverter .CSV files into SunnyData2 DB

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Python >=  version 3 which is meant to work with the pymysql driver

The purpose of this script is to look at each CSV file in a known directory and
parse the time and solar generated power and record that to a MYSQL database

It records the date from line 2, field 10 from the content and creates timestamps, by concatenating the date with the time, 
which is recorded every ten minutes (during the 24 hour day), along with the average power for each slice.

Only values over zero are recorded, as even dark days produce some power and
this keeps the data volume down to the interesting, daytime period.
"""

from os import listdir
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 3

import pymysql
import shutil
import syslog
import os, sys

def connect_to_DB():
    """
    Connect to the SunnyData2 DB
    """
    #Database connection parameters
    h  = ""*********""    # host
    u  = ""*********""    # username
    p  = ""*********""    # password
    d  = ""*********""    # database
    #Pt = 3306            # port

    con = pymysql.connect(host  = h, user  = u, password  = p, database  = d)
    print('Connected to ' + str(d))
    return con

def read_status_table():
    """
        Return list of all parsed files, in alphanumeric filename order from DB table of files
    """
    #Query parameters
    table_name  = 'Files'
    filename    = 'FN'
    filedate    = "FD"
    con=connect_to_DB()
    sql1 = "SELECT %s AS fileName, date(%s) AS fileDate FROM %s ORDER BY date(%s) ASC;" % (filename, filedate, table_name, filedate )
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql1)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def is_dated_csv(filename):
    """
    Return True if filename matches format YY-MM-DD.csv, otherwise False.
    """
    date_format = '%y-%m-%d.csv'

    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(filename, date_format)
        syslog.syslog('SunnyData file ' + filename + ' is a correctly formatted CSV file')
        return True
    except ValueError: # filename did not match pattern
        syslog.syslog('SunnyData file ' + filename + ' is NOT a correctly formatted CSV file')
        pass #'return' terminates a function
    return False

def parse_for_date(filename):
  """
  Read file for the date - from line 2 field 10
  """
  currentFile = open(filename,'r')
  l1 = currentFile.readline() #ignore first line read
  date_line = currentFile.readline() #read second line
  dateLineArray = date_line.split("|") # use | delimiter to make an array
  day_in_question = dateLineArray[-1] #save the last element ,which is the date
  currentFile.close()
  theDate = normalise_date_to_UTF(day_in_question)
  return theDate

def normalise_date_to_UTF(day_in_question):
  """
  Rather wierdly, some days use YYYY.MM.DD format & others use DD/MM/YYYY
  This function normalises either to UTC with a blank time (midnight)
  """
  if '.' in day_in_question: #it's YYYY.MM.DD
    dateArray = day_in_question.split(".")
    dt = (dateArray[0] + dateArray[1] + dateArray[2].rstrip() + '000000')
  elif '/' in day_in_question: #it's DD/MM/YYYY
    dateArray = day_in_question.split("/")
    dt = (dateArray[2].rstrip() + dateArray[1] + dateArray[0] + '000000')
  theDate = datetime.strptime(dt,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
  return theDate #A datetime object

def parse_power_values(path, filename, theDate):
  # timePower = [(),()] #a list that will be assigned two items; the timestamp and the power for that timeslot
  dayPower = [] # A list that will have all the timePowers for the day appended
  currentFile = open(path + filename,'r')
  for i, line in enumerate(currentFile):
    if i <= 7:
      doingSomething = True
      #print 'header' + str(i) + '/ ' + line.rstrip()
    elif ((i > 7) and (i <= 151)):
      lineParts = line.split(';')
      theTime = lineParts[0].split(':')
      theHour = theTime[0]
      theMin = theTime[1]
      timestamp = theDate.replace(hour=int(theHour),minute=int(theMin))
      power = lineParts[1].rstrip()
      if power == '-.---':
        power = 0.000
      if (float(power) > 0):
        dayPower.append([timestamp,power])
    elif i > 151:
     return dayPower
     #break
  currentFile.close()

def add_file_to_Files_table(filenameval, filedateval): # Add the new filename to the DB Files table, as it's now ABOUT TO BE parsed (maybe do this after a successful parse, instead)
    """
        Append the named parsed files to the DB table of files
    """
    #Query parameters
    table_name  = 'Files'
    filename    = 'FN'
    filedate    = 'FD'
    Y           = str(filedateval.year)
    m           = str(filedateval.month)
    d           = str(filedateval.day)
    datestring  = Y+"-"+m+"-"+d
    #D           = datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y%m%d")
    D           = filedateval.date()
    #filedateval2 = datetime.strptime(str(filedateval), "%Y%m%d")
    sql2 = "INSERT INTO %s (%s, %s) VALUES ('%s', '%s');" % (table_name,filename,filedate,filenameval,filedateval)
    #sql2 = "INSERT INTO %s (%s, %s) VALUES ('%s', '%s');" % (table_name,filename,filedate,filenameval,datestring)
    print('SQL Files statement = ' + sql2)
    logcon = connect_to_DB()
    with logcon:
        logcur = logcon.cursor()
        logcur.execute(sql2) 
        logcon.commit()

def add_days_power_to_DTP_table(PowerGenList):
    PowerGenList.__len__
    table_name = 'DTP'
    timestamp_column  = 'DT'
    power_column = 'PWR'
    addcon = connect_to_DB()
    with addcon:
        addcur = addcon.cursor()
        try:
            for row in PowerGenList:
                timestampval    = row[0]
                powerval        = row[1]
                sql             = "INSERT INTO %s (%s,%s) VALUES('%s','%s')" % (table_name, timestamp_column, power_column, timestampval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), powerval)
                print('SQL Date-Power statement = ' + sql)
                addcur.execute(sql)
            addcon.commit()
        except:
            #print 'DB append failed!'
            syslog.syslog('SunnyData DB append failed')
            addcon.rollback()
    

#Query parameters - put into a function for query to find average and total power for a given period (based on attribute values)
# StartYear   = "2019"
# EndYear     = "2019"
# StartMonth  = "1"
# EndMonth    = "2"
# StartDay    = "1"
# EndDay      = "31"

# Main start of program  v--v--v--v--v--v--v--v--v--v--v--v--v--v
path = '/SunnyData/SBEAM/'
syslog.syslog('parsing SunnyData CSVs started ------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>------')
parsedFiles = read_status_table()
for filename in listdir(path):
    if is_dated_csv(filename): # IS a dated CSV
        if any(filename in s for s in parsedFiles): # but HAS been parsed before
            print("file previously parsed: " + filename) #output current file to StdOut
            pass
        else: # Has NOT been parsed before
            print(filename + ' is a previously unparsed dated CSV') #to StdOut
            theDate = parse_for_date(path + filename) #from the file, extracts the date (line 2 field 10) and returns it normalised to UTF
            print('the date is ' + str(theDate))            
            #try creating powergenlist as a list of all the timestamps and power pairs that need to be added
            PowerGenList = parse_power_values(path, filename, theDate) # Reads in power & time, creates a timestamp and appends value into DTP in DB (maybe a clash between timestamp & datetime)            
            add_file_to_Files_table(filename, theDate) # Add the new filename to the DB Files table, as it's now ABOUT TO BE parsed (maybe do this after a successful parse, instead)
            add_days_power_to_DTP_table(PowerGenList)

            #con.close #Disconnect from the database having parsed each file
    else:
        print(filename + " is not a CSV") #output current file to StdOut
#         pass
#^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^--^
```